# Display menu in category and sub category

Tags: categories, menus

I need to show menu with all subcategories for specific category (and sub category).

When code looks like this:

```
                <?php if (is_category('news')) : ?> 
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'news-menu' ) ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if (is_category('articles')) : ?> 
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'articles-menu' ) ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Menu is displayed correctly on main category page - in sidebar is shown full list of subcategories. When i am going to subcategory, for example *news/sales* - menu in sidebar is not appearing. To fix that i changed code like this:

```
                <?php if (is_category('news') || in_category('news')) : ?> 
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'news-menu' ) ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if (is_category('articles') || in_category('articles')) : ?> 
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'articles-menu' ) ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

After that when i am in page of subcategory (let's say *news/sales*) menu is shown correctly, **but** in main category *news* i see both menus for news AND articles.

Any ideas how to make it work? That both main categories and their subpages will show only their own menus, not both menus which re avaliable?

Comment: Have you already tried [has_category()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_category) instead of in_category()?

Comment: Yes, it's showing correct menu in subcategories, but both menus in main category page